# void function throws 'query has no destination for result data' error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function with void return type (Included the entire function):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_avg_prices(p_county character varying, p_municipality character varying, p_district character varying, p_neighbourhood character varying, p_street character varying, p_number character varying, p_avg_rent decimal, p_avg_sale decimal)
 RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _precint_id integer;
    _city_id integer;
    _parish_id integer;
    _county_id integer;

    _address_id integer;

BEGIN
    SELECT place_precint.precint_id INTO _precint_id FROM place_precint WHERE place_precint.name = p_neighbourhood;
    SELECT place_city.city_id INTO _city_id FROM place_city WHERE place_city.name = p_district;
    SELECT place_parish.parish_id INTO _parish_id FROM place_parish WHERE place_parish.name = p_municipality;
    SELECT place_county.county_id INTO _county_id FROM place_county WHERE place_county.name = p_county;

    SELECT full_addresses.f_address_id FROM full_addresses 
    WHERE  full_addresses.county_id = _county_id AND
           full_addresses.parish_id = _parish_id AND
           full_addresses.city_id = _city_id AND
           full_addresses.precint_id = _precint_id AND
           full_addresses.street_name = p_street AND
           full_addresses.number = p_number;

    IF _address_id IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO full_addresses(f_address_id,
                     county_id,
                     parish_id,
                     city_id,
                     precint_id,
                     street_name,
                     number)
        VALUES (nextval('full_addresses_f_address_id_seq'),
            _county_id,
            _parish_id,
            _city_id,
            _precint_id,
            p_street,
            p_number);

        SELECT currval('full_addresses_f_address_id_seq') INTO _address_id;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO building_prices(building_id, 
                    address_id, 
                    avg_sau_sale_price, 
                    avg_sau_rent_price) 
    VALUES (nextval('building_prices_building_id_seq'),
        _address_id,
        p_avg_sale,
        p_avg_rent);
    RETURN;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

If I call it with a select statement like this:

```
SELECT insert_avg_prices(...);
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_avg_prices(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,numeric,numeric) line 16 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

I got no error with the CREATE FUNCTION statement. How to make it work?

Comment: This doesn't make sense - even at the function call level, why would you ever have a function returning void in a select? In any case, many errors only show up when you actually execute the function in question - quite obviously, you've got a `select` somewhere in your function that doesn't store its result in a variable / parameter. Also, I'd avoid using side-effects in functions as a general rule. It's more pain than it's worth. If you're migrating over to Postgres, you really want to learn how Postgres is different from wherever you come from.

Comment: The error is raised by a command inside the function. Show whole body of the function.

Comment: Please `edit` your question (grey link below your question) to show the function body.

Comment: Included the entire function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your function you have a `SELECT` statement, but that statement has nowhere to put its data.

- If [the statement returns exactly 1 row](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), use the `INTO` clause to store the result in a local variable for processing
- If the statement returns multiple rows, use one of the options to [loop over the results](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) or [use a `CURSOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).

Obviously the error is here:

```
SELECT full_addresses.f_address_id FROM full_addresses WHERE ...
```

which should be

```
SELECT full_addresses.f_address_id INTO _address_id FROM full_addresses WHERE ...
```

Note that PL/pgSQL is an interpreted language, which means that the function body is not evaluated for syntactical soundness as in compiled programming languages like Pascal or C++. Therefore you can write a function which only reveals any errors when it is invoked.